# simplexml help how do I parse this?

Tags: php, xml, salesforce

I haven't done any xml projects, so I'm not quite sure what to do with this data...

I'm using curl to make a request to salesforce, and they give me back a response that I need to parse.  I want to use simplexml.  Here's part of the response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
<loginResponse>
<result>
<metadataServerUrl>
https://na6-api.salesforce.com/services/Soap/m/18.0/
</metadataServerUrl>
<passwordExpired>
false
</passwordExpired>
<sandbox>
false
</sandbox>
<serverUrl>
https://na6-api.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/18.0/
</serverUrl>
<sessionId>
!AQ4AQLtDIqY.
</sessionId>
<userId>

</userId>
<userInfo>
<accessibilityMode>
false
</accessibilityMode>
<currencySymbol>
$
</currencySymbol>
<orgDefaultCurrencyIsoCode>
USD
</orgDefaultCurrencyIsoCode>
<orgDisallowHtmlAttachments>
false
</orgDisallowHtmlAttachments>
<orgHasPersonAccounts>
false
</orgHasPersonAccounts>
<organizationId>

</organizationId>
<organizationMultiCurrency>
false
</organizationMultiCurrency>
<organizationName>
Ox 
</organizationName>
<profileId>
sdfgsdfg
</profileId>
<roleId>
sdfgsdfg
</roleId>
<userDefaultCurrencyIsoCode xsi:nil="true"/>
<userEmail>
###@gmail.com
</userEmail>
<userFullName>
### ###
</userFullName>
<userId>
asdfasdf
</userId>
<userLanguage>
en_US
</userLanguage>
<userLocale>
en_US
</userLocale>
<userName>
asdfasdf@gmail.com
</userName>
<userTimeZone>
America/Chicago
</userTimeZone>
<userType>
Standard
</userType>
<userUiSkin>
Theme3
</userUiSkin>
</userInfo>
</result>
</loginResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Anyway, I expected to feed that stuff (we'll call it data) into

```
$results = simplexml_load_string($data);
var_dump($results);
```

And that would give me all the data back... and then to access specific parts, it would be $results->body->loginResponse->blah->blah...

But It's not giving me that, it's not really giving me anything back, just an empty simple xml object...

So one website made me think I might need an XSLT to read this correctly.
Or something else made me think it's because I don't have  at the top.

Help!

Comment: Maybe there's an error at reading the content of the file.... have you E_WARNING's enabled? Maybe you can see what's going on that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SimpleXML but it's not quite as *simple* as you hope due to the use of namespaces (e.g. `soapenv`). Look into using [`SimpleXMLElement::children`](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.children) like:

```
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
$login_response = $sxe->children('soapenv', TRUE)->Body->children('', TRUE)->loginResponse->result;
// Now that we have the <loginResponse> lets take a look at an item within it
echo $login_response->userInfo->userEmail;
```

---

Finally, and importantly, have you had a look at salesforce's [tools & examples](http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Web_Services_API#PHP)?

Answer (score 2):

SimpleXML needs a special treatment for namespaced XML ([ref.](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2005/10/20/simplexml-and-namespaces/))

Answer (score 1):

Mate,

Name spaces usually require you to make a call using children to return the namespaced elements. I would recommend using a soap client like php soapclient, but since I've never used it before there is one other possible option.

```
$results = simplexml_load_string($data);
$xml = $results->children('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
var_dump($xml);
```

I believe that's how it works.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, you may find you have an easier time using a [PHP SoapClient](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) for this task. O'Reilly has a [good tutorial](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2003/07/03/php_amazon_soap.html) on PHP SOAP.

Answer (score 0):

Also checkout the [PHP Toolkit](http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/PHP_Toolkit) for making SOAP calls to Salesforce.com

Answer (score 0):

I try to follow the syntax by salathe. But **children('soapenv', TRUE)** doens't work for me, Jason's **children('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')** work.

Therefore, to read the field value CreatedDate in Salesforce Outbound Message, I need following code:

```
$rcXML->children('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')->Body->children('http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound')->notifications->Notification->sObject->children('urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com')->CreatedDate
```

To help you understand how it work, I write a post with sames code and xml which shall be easier to understand.

http://amigotechnotes.wordpress.com/2013/11/16/parse-xml-with-namespace-by-simplexml-in-php/

Answer (score 0):

[Parsing soap responses with SimpleXML](http://phpave.com/parsing-soap-responses-with-simplexml/) has a brilliant and concise example of multi-namespace XML parsing.

For anyone wanting to get at the RateResponse from the UPS Rating API, here's how :

```
// $client is your SoapClient object

$dom = new DOMDocument;

$dom->loadXML($client->__getLastResponse());

$xml = simplexml_load_string($dom->saveXML(), NULL, NULL, 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');

$RateResponse = $xml->xpath('/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body')[0]->children('rate', true)->RateResponse;

foreach($RateResponse->RatedShipment as $RatedShipment) {
    print_r((array)$RatedShipment);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For SAOP request, we can parse easily with a short code by replacing the SOAP-ENV: tag with blank

```
$response = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>';

$response = html_entity_decode($response);
$response = str_replace(['soapenv:', 'ns1:', ':ns1', 'SOAP-ENV:'], ['', '', '', ''], $response);
$objXmlData = simplexml_load_string($response);
```